# Will $.parent().length be greater than 1?

Tags: jquery

I came across a doubt and i tried figuring it out myself but i think i would better do with some expert opinion out here.

I do know the difference between `$.parent()` and `$.parents()`.

Lets say if i write:

```
$('p#selector').parents();
```

This will return me the parents, grand parents etc of this "p" until the root. And if i write :

```
$('p#selector').parents('.my-parent');
```

This will also take all the parents of this "p" but will return me only those which has the class "my-parent" among the result.

Fair Enough, Now my question is, if i write

```
$('p#selector').parent() or
$('p#selector').parent('.my-parent')
```

it would return me only one element in any case. that is,

```
$('p#selector').parent().length or 
$('p#selector').parent('.my-parent').length will be maximum of one right?
```

So then now i would think that we still filter the result of the `$.parent()` just to make it act like a kind of validation to make sure that things are going fine at our end.

Could anyone think of other uses of filtering the result of `$.parent()` and also is there any situation where `$.parent().length` is greater than one.

one example would be like this:

```
If we combine two selectors and do .parent
$('p#sel1,p#sel2').parent();
This would give me the parent of both "p"
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: One case, is if you are running this on several elements, you want the lements with the correct parent. so $('div').parent() would return many elements...

Comment: Yeah, you've got it quite right. `.parent(selector)` is pretty much a shortcut to `.parent().filter(selector)`. When you're going to use this depends solely on your use case, that is, when your logic requires filtering those elements (or can be used as a way to increase readability at the cost of some performance).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - according to the last example, the OP seems to have figured this out and understands the concept, and the rest of the examples uses ID's, but it's still a good point.

Answer (score 0):

`parent()` selects only the immediate parent element.

Passing a selector, as in `parent('.my-parent')` will filter `only` the immediate parent and return the parent if it matches the selector and nothing if it does not match.

If you need to find the closest parent matching a selector, you'd use `.closest('.my-parent')`

Note that a jQuery selector can contain more than one element, and both `parent()` and `closest()` does not just run on the first element in the collection, but all of them.

In other words, both these methods will return at most one element for each element in the collection it's executed on, and if the selector does not match anything, no elements.

Answer (score 0):

parent() cannot only be 0 or 1. it can also be more.

if you select ***li*** and call *parent()* you can have more than one *ul* in your webpage.

use this html:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
        <li>Bar</li>
        <li>Bar 2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="foorbar">
        <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
        <li>Bar</li>
        <li>Bar 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

then select the following:

```
jQuery('li').parent().length
```

or

```
jQuery('li, ul').parent().length
```

see this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Valtos/dm44Q/